# Why is AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory targeting bin catelog in console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application. And in this application I have created a class libarary project which i reference in the main project. In this class library i have a file which I am trying to get. the code for this:

```
public static string GetPath(string fileName)
{
    char separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    string startupPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string[] pathItems = startupPath.Split(separator);
    string projectPath = string.Join(separator.ToString(),
        pathItems.Take(pathItems.Length - 1)) + ".Handler";
    string path = Path.Combine(projectPath, "WebRequestHandlers\\Files" + separator + fileName);

    return path;
}
```

I have used this in .net web project before and it has worked but for some reason this is my AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory:

> C:\projects\OverWatchServerCall\OverWatchServerCall\bin\Debug\

It should be:

> C:\projects\OverWatchServerCall\OverWatchServerCall\

The file is in the classlibrary project and as I said before this works fine in .net web api projects

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Returns the same path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` isn't defined by the assembly but the hosting environment (i.e. *the application* or *service*).

Once you build a console application your executable and satellite assemblies go to the output path defined in your `*.csproj` file. Default is `bin\$(Configuration)` (for example: `bin\Debug`).

Since the whole executable is being executed in the output path, this is the base directory.

Why in ASP.NET WebAPI projects worked fine in your case? Probably because you're hosting ASP.NET WebAPI in IIS. If you would do it using OWIN/Katana hosted in a Windows service, you would end up with the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for the explenation. I was looking for a fix aswell but in my frustration i forgott to mention it. however i used substring to remove /bin/debug and my code worked

Comment: @Ra3IDeN No problem! You're welcome and I'm glad you solve the issue ;)

Comment: @Ra3IDeN There's no fix here, since the `BaseDirectory` can only be provided when the `AppDomain` is created :(